# How to get first character of string by Jquery or javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a span with inner span and I'm trying to get the first character of the inner span (t) and change its color. I tried to do that with many way with both JavaScript and jQuery and it doesn't work

```js
// with javascript    

var index = document.getElementById('spa');
var indexsl = index.slice(0, 1);
indexsl.style.color = "f00"; //doesn't work

var index = document.getElementById('spa');
var indexsl = index.substring(0, 1);
indexsl.style.color = "f00"; //doesn't work

var index = document.getElementById('spa');
var indexsl = index.charAt(0, 1);
indexsl.style.color = "f00"; //doesn't work


// with jQuery

var index = $('.design span').charAt(0);
index.css('color', '#f00') // doesn't work

var index = $('.design span').substring(0, 1);
index.css('color', '#f00') // doesn't work

var index = $('.design span').slice(0, 1);
index.css('color', '#f00') // doesn't work
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="design">DESIGNED BY <span id="spa">Teodor Victor</span></span>
```

Comment: Em index is an object, not an array. And you cannot assign a style to it

Comment: Javascript strings don't have styles. HTML has styles. You can't just cut a character from a string and give it a style. You would need to add tags to your dom that wrap your character (`span` would be the obvious choice) and assign a style to that tag

Answer (score 2):

Or you can skip the JavaScript and use CSS

```css
span.design > span::first-letter {
  color:red;
}

span {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="design">DESIGNED BY <span>Teodor Victor</span></span>
```

Comment: why span is inline-block

Comment: but i gave it flat right and it will not work perfectly
is there another way

Answer (score 2):

What you want is [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt).

```
var str = 'some string';
console.log(str.charAt(0)); // return 's'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the html:

```
ind=index.innerHTML.split("");
ret="<span class='red'>"+ind.first()+"</span>"+ind.join("");
index.innerHTML=ret;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get first character, insert it with a different font color and then add rest of the content:

```js
var span = $('.design span');
var html = span.html();

span.html("<span style='color:red;'>"+ html.charAt(0)  +"</span>" + html.substring(1,html.length));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="design">DESIGNED BY <span>Teodor Victor</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this ?

```
var header = $('.design span').text().charAt(0);
index.css('color','#f00');
```

Or

```
var header = $('.design span').text().substring(0,1);
index.css('color','#f00');
```